# Is the Sarlacc monster dead?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-book-of-boba-fett, sarlacc

In the god-awful Disney canon novel *Star Wars:  Aftermath:  Life Debt*, we learn that the creature in the Sarlacc Pit was badly wounded in the battle between our heroes and Jabba's forces.

The following is an excerpt of an inner monologue by Malakili, Jabba's former Rancor handler:

> He thought maybe to tame the glorious monstrosity at the bottom of the Great Pit of Carkoon (and, failing that, to throw himself into its maw), but the mighty Sarlacc was injured. Burning wreckage from the sail barge had rained upon it. Already its body— considerably more massive than the mouth exposed from the sliding sands— had been partially unburied, its stoma-tubes slit open, its digesting innards pillaged by industrious Jawas. They pulled out weapons and armor, droids and tools. And skeletons, of course.
>
> The creature of Carkoon had a pure purpose, to wait and to eat, and now it was left to thrash and wail in the grip of pillagers.
>   -  *Star Wars:  Aftermath:  Life Debt*

### Considering the extent of its injuries - being burned by the wreckage of Jabba's sail barge, then being dug up, sliced open by Jawas, and left exposed to the harsh environment of Tatooine - is the creature of Carkoon dead?  Do we know enough about Sarlacc anatomy to speculate on whether it could survive injuries this severe?

Comment: He's not dead, he's pining for the fjords.

Comment: hmmmmm fromi the reading it was not really wounded by the heroes....more by the pillagers

Comment: @Thomas I never said it was wounded by the heroes.  "badly wounded **in the battle between our heroes and Jabba's forces**"

Comment: @WadCheber sry for being a bit non detailed there. What I meant is you said in the battle there. But according to your remaining descriptions it sounded more like the looting after was what REALLY wounded it...the other things were just scratches

Comment: Probably depends on if the Jawas are pillaging the flesh/meat in addition to the other items they found.

Answer (score 4):

**The Sarlacc of Carkoon survived for at least five years.**

The Sarlacc of the Great Pit of Carkoon survived for at least five more years after being burned by the wreckage of Jabba's sail barge in *Star Wars: Episode VI – Return of the Jedi* events before being killed by Fennec Shand with a seismic charge dropped from Slave 1 when she and Boba Fett visit the pit in search of the latter's Beskar armor as shown in episode 4, titled ‘Chapter 4: The Gathering Storm’ of *The Book of Boba Fett*.

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sarlacc

Comment: And is presumably dead now... until they need it for a future series